# jQuery content slideshow plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm in need of a simple content slideshow plugin that would do the job. No controllers or anything fancy, just either fade in new content as the new one fades away or slide in new content

http://jsfiddle.net/bcfjupcz/

I have tried many content sliders but either they didn't work or they were too fancy or overcomplicated to what I need.

Owl slider was the closest one that would fit my needs but I don't know why but It didn't slide the text with the images

Here's the JS code of Owl slider:

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({

    // Most important owl features
    items : 5,
    itemsCustom : false,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [980,3],
    itemsTablet: [768,2],
    itemsTabletSmall: false,
    itemsMobile : [479,1],
    singleItem : false,
    itemsScaleUp : false,

    //Basic Speeds
    slideSpeed : 200,
    paginationSpeed : 800,
    rewindSpeed : 1000,

    //Autoplay
    autoPlay : true,
    stopOnHover : true,

    // Responsive 
    responsive: true,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
    responsiveBaseWidth: window,

    // CSS Styles
    baseClass : "owl-carousel",
    theme : "owl-theme",

    //Lazy load
    lazyLoad : false,
    lazyFollow : true,
    lazyEffect : "fade",

    //Callbacks
    beforeUpdate : false,
    afterUpdate : false,
    beforeInit: false, 
    afterInit: false, 
    beforeMove: false, 
    afterMove: false,
    afterAction: false,
    startDragging : false
    afterLazyLoad : false

})
```

the site I would like to implement the plugin is written on skeleton as I'm only making changes on it

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use the metro.js plugin for slideshow .

http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs

Answer (score 0):

if you need something simple, why not using a pure css3 slider? if you don't have to use js so why would you increase the page load response? there are many of them, i'm sure you can find something you like. take a look at those: http://xdesigns.net/2013/08/css-slider/#